# database not restoring from dump file

Tags: postgresql-9.2, restore, backup

I'm running the following command to create a dump of all database on my production server:

```
prodserver:/# pg_dumpall -U postgres -h 1.1.1.1 > prod.sql
```

on my development box, I also take a backup by doing:

```
devserver:/# pg_dumpall -U postgres -h 1.1.1.1 > dev.sql
```

Then I try to restore the production database on to development like so:

```
devserver:/# psql -f prod.sql -U postgres
```

It runs with no errors. And it appears to be creating tables /import data. ( I know because if I run it a second time, I get messages that certain data already exists / relationships already exist. )

But when I log in like so:

```
psql -U postgres -d databasename
```

the data looks the same as the old dev data.
I tried the following with the production data supposedly restored:

```
select count(*) from widgets;
```

I compare that with the count returned when I'm using the development database and they are the same.

I've also tried restarting postgresql after attempting the restore...it's a no go.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I also checked the following:

I opened up the prod.sql file and found insert statements like:

```
INSERT INTO widgets_to_wiget_groups VALUES (363, 15);
```

And then I did a select statement on the database to see if I had this entry in the table but I don't... maybe it's restoring it but under the context of another user?

**EDIT 2**

I've also tried

```
 psql -f prod.sql -U postgres -h 1.1.1.1
```

but it still didn't work 
As a test I tried restoring the dump file on another new server... same results.  So I checked and saw that in the dump file, there is no CREATE DATABASE command. 
I'm thinking that the original command to dump the file is incorrect...

Comment: Should you explicitly provide the host IP address like this? `psql -U postgres -h 1.1.1.1 -d databasename`

Comment: @difley - thanks for the comment.  I've tried that too.  I'll update the post.  but I also found some other interesting stuff.  check out edit 1.

Comment: In your command for restoring, you don't specify which DB to use.  In this case, `psql` connects to the database named as the user, in this case `postgres`.  Your objects are created there.

Comment: dezso, i just checked and it looks like you're absolutely right.  It's created everything under the postgres database.  so since there is no CREATE DATABASE command in the dump file, should I create the database manually, or perhaps it's better to fix the dump command so it does create the db for me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run

```
CREATE DATABASE databasename;
```

to manually create the db, and then changed the restore command to:

```
devserver:/# psql -f prod.sql -U postgres -d databasename
```